# How do I permanently "trust" my router?

Tags: networking, firefox

Whenever I access my router at https://192.168.1.1 firefox complains that the security certificate is invalid. No amount of permanently storing an exception seems to change its mind. Is there something I can do manually to address this?

Comment: Keep in mind that many routers regenerate the HTTPS certificate on reboot.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion here - if your router is one of those affected, looks like you'll need to wait for a bug-fix.  https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/824450

Answer (score 1):

You should try connecting to https://routers.dns.name instead of https://ip-address. You may be able to find the router's DNS name by viewing the certificate details, and looking at the "issued to" "CN" section